# what is the difference between 海に泳ぎに行きます and 海に行って泳ぎます

Tags: grammar

correct me if i'm wrong.
my teacher said, に行きます mean purpose

this sentence
海に泳ぎに行きます
makes sense if someone asked
来週の休みの目的は何ですか？

what does 海に泳ぎに行きます mean without someone ask question?

Comment: You seem to be asking two different questions in the title and the body.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the に of 泳ぎに indicates purpose.

海に泳ぎに行きます means "[I'm] going to the beach (in order) to swim" in the sense that the intended goal/purpose is the swimming and going to the beach is the means by which the goal can be achieved.

Incidentally 来週の休みの目的は何ですか？ sounds somewhat strange in this context if you are just asking someone what their plans are for the weekend. If that is the context, then something like 来週の休みの**予定**は何ですか？ would make more sense.

Comment: FWIW, 海に行く more naturally translates to "going to the beach".  By extension, I'd *assume* it works if you're going to like a "boardwalk", "wharf", "pier", or other type of entertainment area next to the ocean/sea, though I'm not positive.

Comment: Fair point - edited.

Comment: Come to think of it, "来週の休みの目的は何ですか？" may sound legit if one requested to take some days off work "next week", and the boss asks "what's the purpose of taking days off next week?".

Comment: My point is not that the sentence is ungrammatical, but that it is not appropriate in the specific context the OP is intending, which I assume is the standard meaning.